# Is it possible to install a Windows 10 software in Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, wine, minecraft

I had Windows 10 and I bough Minecraft for that OS, but my hard disk drive failed, and later I installed Ubuntu in a new external hard disk drive.

As Microsoft Store told me that I own the game and I can reinstall it on my devices. I am trying to recover it.

First I installed wine (My teacher told me that with the help of wine one could run a Windows program), then I tried to download it from the official microsoft page, without success. Then when I tried doing the same in my cousin's PC which has Windows 10, I realized that it also needed the Microsoft Store.

So my question is: Is it possible to install minecraft for Windows 10 in Ubuntu?

If the answer is yes: Is there a way to do so?

If the answer is no: Why not?

Comment: Ubuntu is NOT a drop-in replacement for Windows. It is a completely different computer operating system. Ubuntu does NOT run Windows programs natively. Wine may (or may not) run some Windows programs that you have already downloaded, but compatibility is not guaranteed. Wine has no connection to the Microsoft Store (you need to run *real* Windows for that). Most Minecraft players on Ubuntu use the Java version (I run a server using the Java version). The Java version does not require Wine. Any search engine will happily provide a dozen instructions for it.

Comment: wine is not worth your time. Use virtualbox or vmware to install windows in Ubuntu and then games in Windows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to run Windows 10 UWP apps on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/991858/is-it-possible-to-run-windows-10-uwp-apps-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

At least for .appx files it seems possible, see [Is it possible to run Windows 10 UWP apps on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/991858/is-it-possible-to-run-windows-10-uwp-apps-on-ubuntu/1300897#1300897)

Download appx file from store via https://store.rg-adguard.net/ (you have to save the file via the context menu).

```
unzip -d <output-dir> <file>.appx
```

Then check for the executable and run it with wine.

Hope it helps :)