# Is it possible to run a paid Microsoft store app on Ubuntu?

Tags: microsoft

I am trying to get MSFS to run on Ubuntu but I bought it through the Microsoft store instead of steam. Is there any way I can run it on Ubuntu?

Comment: The short answer is no.

Comment: MSFS doesn’t even run on Ubuntu if you had bought it through the steam store, so that wouldn’t help matters.

Comment: @Tim yeah it does. Although its support for joysticks ends up being a bit poor, which kind of defeats the point :)

Answer (score 14):

## **It depends**

There are some options, you may try to achieve this:

- run a virtual machine with Windows on Ubuntu
- contact your software distributor, explain your situation and ask to exchange your ms store key to steam one
- some UWP (Windows Store) apps still can be run through wine, as described in the [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/991858/is-it-possible-to-run-windows-10-uwp-apps-on-ubuntu/1300897#1300897)

Answer (score 9):

### Not for beginners

1. Ubuntu is not a Windows clone.
2. Ubuntu does not run Windows executables natively.

   - Some Windows software is compatible with Wine+Ubuntu.
   - Most Windows software will run in a Virtual Machine on an Ubuntu Host. But that VM Guest must run Windows.
3. Ubuntu has no interface with the Microsoft Store.

   - It is possible, using [third party sites](https://askubuntu.com/a/1300897/19626) to fool the Microsoft Store into working with a Linux install. However, Microsoft provides no support for that, and we certainly don't recommend entrusting your Windows Store credentials to shady websites.

Generally, if you want to use Microsoft Store software, do so the way it was designed to be used...from Windows.